# Only blobs formatted as VHDs can be imported

Tags: linux, azure, vhd, azure-cli2

I am following these https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/upload-vhd instructions to create a VM in Azure. At this stage though

> az disk create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myManagedDisk \
>     --source https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mydisks/myDisk.vhd

i get the following error

> Only blobs formatted as VHDs can be imported.

I believe the VHD is a Linux OS.

Any ideas to what i have missed or does someone have a link to a better resource that can help me get this VM installed?

Comment: When you uploaded, did you mark the VHD as a page file and not a blob file? "az storage blob upload" step

Comment: I copied that step and just changed the names to match my resource groups and storage accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow the guide you mentioned above and I am able to create the disk without any issue.

[image: created]

As CtrlDot mentioned above, please make sure that the uploaded vhd is marked as page blob.

To verify this, please run the command below:

[image: verify]

If it is page blob and you are still getting error, then please make sure that your source vhd has met the following requirements:

1. The type of the source file is vhd. (not vhdx) Otherwise, please follow this [guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cbernier/2013/08/29/converting-hyper-v-vhdx-to-vhd-file-formats-for-use-in-windows-azure/) to convert the vhdx to a vhd file.
2. The vhd file is fixed size and it is aligned to 1 MB. Otherwise, please follow this [guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2011/12/28/converting-to-a-fixed-virtual-hard-diskthe-easy-way/) to convert the dynamic vhd to a fixed one.

Comment: The content i got back indicated it was a page blob 
"properties": {
    "appendBlobCommittedBlockCount": null,
    "blobType": "PageBlob",
    "contentLength": 1856475136,
but unlike your example above i got no metadata info
"metadata": {},

Comment: As you suggested i converted the VHD from dynamic to fixed using the guide and it was successful. Thank you for the information.